# bootstrap: how to stylise navbar when using scrollspy?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I have started a one page project with bootstrap and I have some issues with scrollspy because I need to use class nav which is changing my navbar style (my-style). 

Can anyone advise how to make scrollspy working without nav class or a way to remove initial nav class properties without changing bootstrap.min.css?

This is the the code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
        .navigation {height:50px;vertical-align:middle;}
        .my-style li {display:inline;margin-left:30px;}
        .my-style li a {font-size:22px;color:black;text-decoration:none;text-transform:uppercase;}
        .my-style li a:hover {color: red;}
        .my-style li.active a {color: red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navigation">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navigation">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="my-style nav">
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.navigation').scrollspy();
    </scipt>
</body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Mario, If I'm understanding correctly you want to style the `.nav` without modifying bootstrap-min.css? This is very simple, just add everything you want to modify about bootstrap in a new .CSS file and place it below your bootstrap-min.css file so the style you add to it make the cut (Meaning that they cascade properly)

Comment: So I'm understanding correctly? If so I'm going to post an answer to this so people know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to not modify the core files as you are carefully avoiding (good stuff).

### [Here is a working demo of the explanation below](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/YDXXQ/)

As you are aware, when writing CSS if you do this:

```
div {
  background: #666;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

and then you do this anywhere that comes after the above snippet:

```
div {
  background: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

It's safe to say that the `<div>` will be black (`#000`) because it's defined later (means below) the dark gray `#666`.

So with that said, since you may come across other `.nav` classes in your build, it's good that you are giving your `.nav` another class that is unique so you can hook to it without affecting all the `.nav`'s on your markup.

I would recommend that you make a new stylesheet (probably call it: custom.css) and put a link to it below the `bootstrap-min.css` inside your `<head>` element so any style you do to modify something that comes stock in a certain with with bootstrap will be overwritten by your `custom.css` file.

Simply try this:

```
.nav.my-style {
  background: #000;
}
```

You will see that the background will turn black and you successfully did that without modifying the core bootstrap CSS file.

Now this looks a little weird, and if what you wanted to do was modify the whole bar then you would modify the .navbar-inner as it's the one with all the styles you probably want to change.

### [Here is another fiddle of that in action](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/37H8s/)

Remember to vote up if this was helpful or to select it as an answer so other people searching StackOverflow can find this helpful too.